# Postgresql dynamic query with named parameters inside

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic-sql

Is there a possibility to write dynamic SQL, where I can use parameter names inside the code?

The following syntax I know, makes long code completely unclear and hard to figure out the sense without digging and mapping the parameters.

```
format ($$ select * from %1$s $$ , tableName_1)
```

I would like to somehow have it like

```
select * from tableName_1
```

Comment: Its is `I%` not `1%`.  And it is not possible. In `plpgsql` there is the ability to do dynamic SQL, but it is not that different from the above. For information on that see [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

Comment: Of course the syntax I mentioned is possible... I'm already using it and it works.
The numbers represents parameters in their order, and can be used like this:
format ($$ select * from %1$s where %3$s is true and %2$s > 1 $$ , paremeter1, parameter2, parameter3)

Comment: Yes it is possible but for identifiers you should be using `I` to get proper quoting.

Answer (score 0):

Sample1:

> using `format` function. By using `format` you can write all parameters under same name. And values will be set to params orderly.

```
execute format('select * from %s.%s' , p_schema, p_table);

--Result:
select * from public.mytable
```

Sample2:

```
execute 'select * from ?.?' using p_schema, p_table;
```

Sample3:

```
execute 'select * from $1.$2' using p_schema, p_table;
```

Comment: But I want just the opposite, so having the code like 
select * from p_schema.p_table, so if my function is really long I can see on the first look which parameters are on certain places